# Unable to activate constraint with anchors IOS xamarin

Tags: ios, forms, xamarin, mobile, controls

I have problem with xamarin iOS app, when I install my app, it throws error on on autosuggestionBox (control for search) then it works normaly without any problems.

I don't know how I can detect it, i have stack trace, part of code :
**Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSGenericException Reason: Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x281facb80 "UITableView:0x124192400.top"> and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x281fad800 "UITextField:0x117fff380.bottom"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal**.**

App

**at dotMorten.Xamarin.Forms.AutoSuggestBox.set_ItemsSource (System.Collections.IList value) [0x00000] in E:\GitHub\dotMorten\XamarinFormsControls\AutoSuggestBox\AutoSuggestBox.cs:197**

Comment: Could you post code about autosuggestionBox to provide more infromation？

Comment: I think that problem is the same on tihis link https://github.com/dotMorten/XamarinFormsControls/issues/76                                                     It thorws error in this line                                                                                                      autoSuggestBox.ItemsSource = (System.Collections.IList) SortingAlgorithm(autoSuggestBox.Text.ToLower(), stringList);